# hadoop, word count in paragraph

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

Normally, Hadoop examples define how to do word count for a file or multiple files, the result of word count 'll be from entire set!

i wish to do **wordcount for each paragraph** and store in seperate files like paragh(i)_wordcnt.txt.

how to do it? (the issue is mapper runs for entire set and reducer collects output finally!

**can i do something like if i reach a specific mark write results!**
)
say if filecontent:

```
para1
...
para2
...
para3
...
```

can i do like on seeing para2 write results of wordcount of para1? or if other way writing each para in seperate file how to do like this sequence

```
   loop: 
   file(i)(parai)->Mapper->Reducer->multipleOutput(output-file(i))->writetofile(i);
   i++;
   goto loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the RecordReader read a paragraph at a time. See this question: [Overriding RecordReader to read Paragraph at once instead of line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610449/overriding-recordreader-to-read-paragraph-at-once-instead-of-line)

Answer (score 0):

I am writing the basic funda as how we can do it.

I think we have to run linked mapper and reducer for this proccess.

In the first mapper you have to use [RecordReader](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/RecordReader.html) and set its key as whole paragraph. This way we will get as many keys as paragraph you have.Then you need to use the reducer as [identity reducer](http://wikidoop.com/wiki/Hadoop/MapReduce/Reducer) and again let the output of reducer to a new mapper which will get paragraph as key.

Now since you have paragraph in your new mapper ,you can tweak the famous [word count code](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module3.html) for your need.(Just replacing KEYS with VALUES here and all rest will be same).

Since you have nested mapper in a reducer ,getting the word count of a paragraph in separate files will be easy.

Please tell if my method is not correct.